# Why is my beautifulsoup parsing just a meta tag?

Tags: python

So i have been working on something that i wanted to try to test out with the `snk` checkout page and i needed the html code for it to work, but when i parse the data, all i see is a header with a meta tag in it. I am a bit new to this kind of stuff, but is there a way to get past this and get the actual html?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://shopnicekicks.com/2192362/checkouts/009e91a67c7040239a40bdaafb11e671?_ga=2.173244707.1809809349.1528354207-1821146214.1528354207"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
searches = soup.find("div", class_="field__input-wrapper")

print(soup)
print(searches)
```

The `print(soup)` portion is what im worried about mainly

**this is what it outputs**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="0; url=https://shopnicekicks.com/2192362/checkouts/009e91a67c7040239a40bdaafb11e671?_ga=2.173244707.1809809349.1528354207-1821146214.1528354207&amp;no_cookies_from_redirect=1" http-equiv="refresh"/>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: your url is invalid. the part that reads `009e91a67c7040239a40bdaafb11e671` is a session identifier which dies quickly and is not transferable. just delete it

Comment: so i removed that part from the url and i retrieved some html code, but rather, it gave me the code for a 404 error page that i got redirected to. maybe the session identifier is essential for leading to the checkout page?